# JavaScript sort dates with a custom boolean value

Tags: javascript, date

I have an array of objects, these objects contains dates and one of them contains an

```
noDate: true
```

value.
I would like to sort these dates, current I am able to sort them like this:

```
data.sort((a, b) => a.date - b.date)
```

But I need to sort them so the object with the noDate true value becomes the first one in the array.
I tried this, but it does not work properly:

```
data.sort((a, b) => a.noDate === true ? -1 : a.date - b.date)
```

Comment: Does your `sort` not already do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the boolean/`undefined` value and take the delta by converting the value to a negated boolean value first. Then sort by `date`.

```js
const
    data = [
        { id: 0, noDate: true },
        { id: 1, date: new Date('2021-10-30') },
        { id: 2, date: new Date('2020-10-30') },
        { id: 3, noDate: true },
    ];

data.sort((a, b) => !a.noDate - !b.noDate || a.date - b.date);
console.log(data);

data.sort((a, b) => !b.noDate - !a.noDate || a.date - b.date);
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: this works great, but what do you mean with delta? And how would you sort this to make the noData the last item in the sort, that would be interesting aswell :)

Comment: delta means the difference of two values, here one same property of two objects, like your `date` in the question.  for getting an opposite result switch `a` and `b`.